# RC-IamErrorResponse - Account context in the query param is different from the account context in the token

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to get resource groups via an api key.

First, I authenticate to IAM...

```py
apikey = 'myapikeyvalue'

self.log.debug('Authenticating to IAM')
url = self.iam_endpoint + '/identity/token'
data = "apikey={}&grant_type=urn%3Aibm%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Aapikey".format(apiKey)
headers = { 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic Yng6Yng=" 
    }
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
token_type, access_token = # get token_type and access_token from response
```

Then I receive the account_id ...

```py
url = self.iam_endpoint + '/v1/apikeys/details'
headers = { 
    "IAM-Apikey": apiKey,
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'authorization': '{} {}'.format(token_type, access_token),
    'cache-control': 'no-cache', 
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
response = self._request(url=url, http_method='get', description='_get_account_id', additional_headers=headers)
account_id = response.json()['account_id']
```

Next, I try to retrieve the resource_groups ...

```py
url = self.region.rc_endpoint() + '/v1/resource_groups?account_id=' + account_id
response = self.client._request(url=url, http_method='get', description='get_resource_groups')
return response.json()
```

However, this results in:

```py
{
 "error_code":"RC-IamErrorResponse",
 "message":"Account context in the query param is different from the account context in the token.",
 "status_code":401,
 "transaction_id":"7e89f6873e1bd4f92d57829e0f08f4ad"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, returned value seems to be of the format: xxxxxxxxxxxY-YYYY and we only need the x's.  This worked for me

```
return account_id.split('-')[0][:-1]
```